# ElasticSearch multilayer nested properties

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl, elasticsearch-query

I have an index mapping like this

```json
"mappings": {
      "properties": {
        "filter": {
          "type": "nested",
          "properties": {
            "Hersteller": {
              "type": "nested",
              "properties": {
                "id": {
                  "type": "text",
                  "analyzer": "analyzerFilter",
                  "fielddata": true
                },
                "value": {
                  "type": "text",
                  "analyzer": "analyzerFilter",
                  "fielddata": true
                }
              }
            },
            "Modell": {
              "type": "nested",
              "properties": {
                "id": {
                  "type": "text",
                  "analyzer": "analyzerFilter",
                  "fielddata": true
                },
                "value": {
                  "type": "text",
                  "analyzer": "analyzerFilter",
                  "fielddata": true
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "id": {
          "type": "text",
          "analyzer": "analyzerFilter"
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

There are 2 nested layers filter.Modell. I need a query to get all unique filter.Modell.value where  filter.Hersteller.value is equal some predefined value.
I am trying first without any condition

```json
{
  "size": 4,
  "aggs": {
    "distinct_filter": {
      "nested": { "path": "filter" },
      "aggs": {
        "distinct_filter_modell": {
          "nested": {
            "path": "filter.Modell",
            "aggs": {
              "distinct_filter_modell_value": {
                "terms": { "field": "filter.Modell.value" }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And I get issue like

```json
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "parsing_exception",
        "reason": "Unexpected token START_OBJECT in [distinct_filter_modell].",
        "line": 1,
        "col": 144
      }
    ],
    "type": "parsing_exception",
    "reason": "Unexpected token START_OBJECT in [distinct_filter_modell].",
    "line": 1,
    "col": 144
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tried ? where are you stuck ?

Comment: @Paulo I am trying first without any condition

-d'{"size": 4, "aggs":{"distinct_filter": {"nested":{"path":"filter"}, "aggs":{"distinct_filter_modell": {"nested":{"path":"filter.Modell","aggs":{"distinct_filter_modell_value":{"terms":{"field":"filter.Modell.value"}}}}}}}}}'

And I get issue like 
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"parsing_exception","reason":"Unexpected token START_OBJECT in [distinct_filter_modell].","line":1,"col":144}],"type":"parsing_exception","reason":"Unexpected token START_OBJECT in [distinct_filter_modell].","line":1,"col":144},"status":400}

Comment: Add this to your question ;)

Comment: @Paulo it's added

Comment: Looking at your error it is the query that is not correctly built!